# How to force lstlisting caption names and numbers to always appear, even when captions are empty?

Tags: listings, captions, environments

I noticed `lstlisting` environment seems to supress the caption name and number when no caption is specified.

See the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C}
\begin{document}
The listing below will have no caption.
\begin{lstlisting}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
Now this code will show the caption. 
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=This is the caption]
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The only solution I found was to set the caption to be an empty space and to get rid of the separator, but this solution does not look very nice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=none}
\begin{document}
This is not an elegant solution, but works:
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=\ ]
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define a default caption (I used `\relax`) and setup a caption format that checks whether the given caption is different. The trick is knowing that the caption text is stored in `\lst@caption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,caption}

\lstset{language=C,caption=\relax}

\makeatletter
%% define a caption format; if the caption
%% is the default (\relax), the separator is
%% not printed; as long as no caption text
%% starts with \relax, this will work
\DeclareCaptionFormat{alsoempty}{%
  #1\if\relax\expandafter\noexpand\lst@caption\else#2#3\fi}
\makeatother
%% set this format as the default for lstlisting
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=alsoempty}

\begin{document}

The listing below will have no caption.
\begin{lstlisting}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
Now this code will show the caption. 
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=This is the caption]
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]